# useState inside useEffect update datas only after re-render in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to call a asyncronimous function inside a useEffect hook in order to avoid refetching my datas at every re-render but by doing that, my datas dosen't update before the next re-render.

My datas should load a chart, so basically my chart shows up only after re-render.

```
const [PricesArray, setPricesArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
      const history = Fetcher.fetchPairReservesFromBlock(3, "0xa559D24c7f9534ec19676Cd98421267EA9e02478", blockNumber, 5);
      var cast = Promise.resolve(history);
      cast.then(function(value) {
        setPricesArray(value);
      });    

    }, [])
```

Later, i try to use `PricesArray` to populate my chart like this:

```
const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Price in $',
      data: PricesArray,
      borderColor: 'rgb(39, 146, 214)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1,
    },
  ],
};
```

My chart finally load but only after a re-render caused by another function. This does not happen when i fetch my datas without useEffect (but then i get re-fetching at each render).

I tried to use another useEffect that is called on PricesArray's update:

```
   useEffect(() => {
        setBeforePricesArray(PricesArray);
    }, [PricesArray])
```

I can check that this call is executed right after the first useEffect but my chart still dosen't load before the next re-render.

Comment: *"...my chart shows up only after re-render."* Yes, that's how `useEffect` works. The component is rendered and applied to the DOM, then any effect callbacks are called.

Comment: *"My chart finally load but only after a re-render caused by another function."* That sounds like the main issue. We can't help you from the bits and pieces of information and code above, though, unfortunately.  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). (The link explains how to handle mocking up a data fetch.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I kind of understood that, indeed. I'm new to react (i'm used of Vuejs), all i want to do is to avoid my call to be re-run at each render and the best way i found is to use useEffect. Do you know of any other method to do the same thing ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder First of all, thanks a lot for your insights. Much appreciated.

Unfortunately, the component(s) causing the re-render are outside my actual functional component and it would be way too much hassle for anyone to look at my problem this way.

Comment: I'm afraid without an MRE or similar, I don't think we'll be able to help you much. [This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415128/) may help (or may not). Fundamentally, you're doing the right thing in the code you've shown (though I don't see why you have `Promise.resolve` there). That will run the effect after the first render (*after*), get the information, and then set it -- which **will** trigger a re-render. So if you're not seeing your chart when that re-render occurs, something is happening not covered by the code above. Good luck!

Comment: Unrelated to your main problem: Why *are* you using `Promise.resolve` there? Is `history` a thenable that isn't a native promise? If so, you probably want to handle rejection as well as fulfillment.

Comment: I'm actually not forced to resolve a premise, i probably will not. It is more of an artifact.. Anyway i have tried the same code without the premise and it dosen't change anything.